# Adicionar um display none em uma div

Tags: php, css, html5

Estou tentando fazer um preg_replace para adicionar um style na div de id="conteudo", porém não tive muito sucesso, alguém teria uma ideia melhor?

**Tentativa**

```
$html = preg_replace('/<div id="conteudo">.*<\/div>/s','<div id="conteudo" style="display:none;">',$html);
echo $html
```

**Page.php**

```
<div id="conteudo">
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0; ">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center; padding:8px;">
            <label style="color:white;"><b> Conteudo</b></label>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao contrário do que foi dito na outra resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396042/3635, ele pode sim fazer PARSE de strings em DOM e setar valores nos atributos, como `style=""`, mas regex é um caminho complicado para isso, não tem porque reinventar a roda:

```
$html = '... Conteudo do HTML ...';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// "conteudo" é o ID, não adicione o #
$tagConteudo = $doc->getElementById('conteudo');

$tagConteudo->setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
```

---

### Não precisa de JavaScript e nem de "parses"

Antes de tentar qualquer coisa devo dizer, não precisa setar o `style=""`, usar jQuery, JavaScript ou fazer parse do DOM é trabalho desnecessário (na verdade neste caso usar isto é um baita exagero), basta usar a tag `<style>` e concatenar com a string na variavel `$html` que você já tem, exemplo simples:

```
$sumir = '<style>
#conteudo {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>';

$html = $html . $sumir;
echo $html;
```

**Nota:** coloquei o `!important` para impedir que outras folhas de estilo tenham prioridade

Answer (score 0):

O `PHP` é uma linguagem de servidor, ou seja, ela não manipula elementos na página e sim dados que são tratados no `server`.
Ela não serve para fazer o que você está tentando, nesse caso aconselho que faça via `JS/Jquery`.

```
$("#conteudo").attr("style","display:none");
```

Isso resolve seu problema!